# How do I use gparted from the command line?

Tags: hard-drive, display, gparted, gui

I'm super new to Ubuntu and have basic understanding of how to use it. I'm trying to set up a Minecraft server and want to have it backed up onto a second HDD. I've installed the server distro of Ubuntu but can't figure out how to format the second drive. When I tried to use parted it said it couldn't write to certain sectors because they were in use. A little Google use later and I figured I would try gparted. When I try to run gparted though I get a display error: Gym Warning cannot open DISPLAY.

Is this because I don't have a gui installed?

Comment: Yes. Also, you shouldn't modify partitions that are in use. Either unmount them, or boot to a live USB and use GParted from there.

Comment: You could use the [gparted Live ISO](http://gparted.org/livecd.php).

Comment: So since it is a separate drive I would unmount it and then use parted to format it?

Comment: As you are running Ubuntu Server, there is no X-windows, hence gparted will not work, 'parted' should be used, but it is probably trying to modify a partition in use. As Ziazis suggested, boot Live USB and use its gparted.

Answer (score 5):

The command line version of `gparted` (g stands for graphical) is `parted`. Making mistakes with parted is easy to do... make a backup of your personal files even it is not on the disk you expect to alter.

> but can't figure out how to format the second drive

You can only change disks that are not mounted.

- `fdisk -l | grep '^Disk'` will list all disks. It could be `sdb` (`b` being the 2nd disk in your system).
- Find the one you need to format. `umount` it if it is mounted.
- `fdisk /dev/sdb` will let you partition `sdb` (change it to the one you want)
- `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb1` (change it to the one you want) will format partition 1  to ext4. If you made more do the others too.

You can use `sudo` in front of the commands but doing `sudo -i` before the commands lets you use "root".

If you have direct access to the machine you could also use a [gparted live session](http://gparted.org/livecd.php). It works the same as an Ubuntu live session except it boots gparted.

Comment: parted is not command line version of gparted. Both GParted and KDE Partition Manager use a little bit of libparted for some tasks but implement a lot of other stuff themselves. E.g. there is no way in parted to move/resize partitions without loosing data.

Comment: gparted is a GTK+ GUI front-end for parted.

Comment: @AndriusŠtikonas This guide for parted seems to show resizing a partition without losing data: https://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/html_node/parted_31.html

Comment: @carlin.scott Well, I'm not sure how many different file systems that "resize" command supports. I thought they removed ext support, only left FAT and HFS support. And definitely it can't resize btrfs or move partitions. You need to use btrfsresize and change geometry of the partitions in the right order. So need to use more than one tool.

Comment: @AndriusŠtikonas Does GParted do all of that?

Comment: @carlin.scott Yes, both GParted and KDE Partition Manager (KPM) have a lot of extra code to do all this. For example when you move partition, gparted and KPM themselves read tens of MB from the disk and write it somewhere else and repeat until the whole partition is moved. There is no function in libparted to move partition even though parted itself has a move command. Don't know why nobody did it for libparted.

The code that interracts with libparted is no more than 5% of KPM code. And right now I'm actually writing another backend for KPM not based on libparted (uses sfdisk directly)

Comment: Links to code example

https://github.com/GNOME/gparted/blob/master/src/GParted_Core.cc#L3241

https://cgit.kde.org/kpmcore.git/tree/src/jobs/job.cpp#n40

Comment: @AndriusŠtikonas thanks for the thorough responses. So Rinzwind was wrong in his assertions. This frustrates me though because I was hoping to use a CLI to grow a partition for all of my team's VMs but apparently I can't script that without digging into the gparted code and creating my own library or modifying gparted.

Comment: Why would you need gparted for that? and don't you think that bit of into HAS to be in the question? You ---enlarge--- the disk from vmware(/virtualbox) and then resize so the new empty space can be added to the old partition. (and YES parted can do that). see 2.2: https://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/html_chapter/parted_2.html resizing from gparted is  as simple as this `parted /dev/sda resize 1 52 104 mkfs 2 fat16`

Comment: Oh and to make this perfectly crystal: you do NOT use partitioning tools inside a VM to enlarge a partition if the free space needs to come from the HOST. You do that in the HOST.

Comment: @carlin.scott I wouldn't say Rinzwind was wrong, just some small inaccuracies and I was a bit picky (but you can change some partitions while they are mounted, btrfs can be both grown and shrunk, ext4 can only be grown without unmounting). You can still use command line tools for a lot of operations from your script. It's just that you need to be more careful. For growing you first resize partition boundaries, e.g. delete partition, then recreate it with larger boundaries, then resize file system with fs specific tools. Shrinking is opposite order. Moving can be done with sfdisk --move-data